# Функция prev и next

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет. Сделал две кнопки "вперед" и "назад" и что-то типа слайдера. К нему привязал такой скрипт:

```
$("img.menu-links__images").bind("click", function() {
    var i = $("img.menu-links__images.current").index(this);
    if (i != 1) {
        $("#left-control").bind("click", function() {
            for (j = i; j <= i; j--) {
                if (j != 1) {
                    $("img.current")
                        .removeClass("current")
                        .replaceWith(prev);
                    var prev = $("img.menu-links__images")
                        .eq(j)
                        .clone()
                        .appendTo("#images")
                        .addClass("current");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Где .menu-links__images - изображения,
Класс current добавляется к активному изображению,
Блок с id "images" содержит картинку с классом current,
а "#left-control" - кнопка, нажав на которую должна происходить смена изображений.

Но он не работает. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему? Заранее спасибо.

**Обновление**

Подредактировал код:

```
$("img.menu-links__images").bind("click", function() {
    var i = $("img.menu-links__images.current").index(this);
    if (i != 1) {
        $("#left-control").bind("click", function() {
            for (j = i; j < 1; j--) {
                if (j != 1) {
                    var prev = $("img.menu- links__images").eq(j).clone().appendTo("#imagesOfBox");
                    $("img.current").removeClass("current").replaceWith(prev);
                    $("img.menu-links__images").eq(j).addClass("current");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Все равно. После нажатия на кнопку сайт виснет.

**Обновление 2**

Я кажись понял и опять внес небольшие изменения:

```
$("img.menu-links__images").bind("click", function() {
    var i = $("img.menu-links__images.current").index(this);
    if (i != 1) {
        $("#left-control").bind("click", function() {
            for (j = i; j > 1; j--) {
                if (j != 1) {
                    var prev = $("img.menu-links__images").eq(j).clone().appendTo("#imagesOfBox");
                    $("img.current").replaceWith(prev);
                    $("img.current").removeClass("current");
                    $prev.addClass("current");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Но все так и не работает.

Comment: @rsandrey, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

```
$("img.menu-links__images").bind("click", function() {
    var i = $("img.menu-links__images.current").index(this);
    if (i != 1) {
        $("#left-control").bind("click", function() {
            // Первая ошибка: бесконечный цикл.
            // Рассмотрим на примере.
            // Читаем: пусть j = 5. Уменьшаем j на 1, пока j <= 5 (всегда верно)
            for (j = i; j <= i; j--) {
                // избыточное условие, не дающее нужного результата.
                // Правильнее будет использовать условие в цикле вот так:
                // for (j = i; j > 1; j--)
                if (j != 1) {
                    $("img.current")
                        .removeClass("current")
                        // Вторая ошибка: удаление элемента вместо замещения.
                        // Почему происходит удаление:
                        // переменная prev используется до своего объявления.
                        // в итоге выражение равносильно .replaceWith(undefined)
                        .replaceWith(prev);
                    var prev = $("img.menu-links__images")
                        .eq(j)
                        .clone()
                        .appendTo("#images")
                        .addClass("current");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Ну и дальше сами смотрите. Без рабочего примера что-то еще сказать будет тяжело.

Comment: Подредактировал код:
$("img.menu-links__images").bind("click", function() {
var i = $("img.menu-links__images.current").index(this);
if(i != 1) {
$("#left-control").bind("click", function() {
for(j = i; j < 1; j--) {
if(j != 1) {
var prev = $("img.menu-links__images").eq(j).clone().appendTo("#imagesOfBox");
$("img.current").removeClass("current").replaceWith(prev);
$("img.menu-links__images").eq(j).addClass("current");
}
}
});
}
});
Все равно. После нажатия на кнопку сайт виснет.

Comment: @rsandrey, у вас так и остался бесконечный цикл.  

    j = i; j < 1; j--

заменить на

    j = i; j > 1; j--

Comment: Да, не заметил. Уже лучше - не зацикливается. Но все же опять не работает. Изображения не заменяются.

Comment: Я кажись понял и опять внес небольшие изменения:  
$("img.menu-links__images").bind("click", function() {  
var i = $("img.menu-links__images.current").index(this);  
if(i != 1) {  
$("#left-control").bind("click", function() {  
for(j = i; j > 1; j--) {  
if(j != 1) {  
var prev = $("img.menu-links__images").eq(j).clone().appendTo("#imagesOfBox");  
$("img.current").replaceWith(prev);  
$("img.current").removeClass("current");  
$prev.addClass("current");  
}  
}  
});  
}  
});  

Но все так и не работает.

Comment: @rsandrey, вместо $prev надо $(prev). Однако я еще раз повторяю, без рабочего примера, например, на http://jsfiddle.net/ помочь вам вслепую будет тяжело.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/scbqe7c8/  Правда стили я упростил, но суть та же.

Answer (score 1):

Я вам хочу сообщить, что если вы в DOM делаете например append() уже имеющегося элемента, то он **переместится** с предыдущего места. т.е.

```
 $('.image').first().appendTo('.imageContainer');
```

возьмет первую картинку и переместит ее на передний план imageContainer.

надеюсь эта информация будет вам полезна.

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/snjhevhk/

Comment: А можно конкретно на этом примере? Как сделать простую замену фотографий?

Comment: этот пример очень замороченный - я с ним разбираться ни малейшего желания не имею :)

Comment: Понимаю) Но хоть наводку какую-нибудь можно?

Comment: если порядок картинок не важен, то вот http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/snjhevhk/6/ а это если важен http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/snjhevhk/8/